# Passing variables that have been uploaded into a DIV via AJAX into the same DIV and replace the contents with results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I currently have form results from a form on a page update into a DIV on submit parsing via a PHP.  The PHP file produces another form which I need to then pass to another PHP and update the DIV where it was previously with results.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div id="content">
  <div id="options">
    <form id="form1">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Date:</td>
          <td><input name="date" type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Size:</td>
          <td><input name="size" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="result"> </div>
</div>
```

And my AJAX script to load the results from this form into DIV 'result'.

```
    <script>
            $(function() { 
            $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      url: 'ajax/ajax-details.php',
                      success: function(response) {
                          $('#result').html(response); 
                      }
                  });
              });
             });
     </script>
```

My PHP file I want it to parse to is called 'ajax/ajax-info.php' with the form name I want to pass the info from is called "id='info'".

I think I'm nearly there with my current script.

```
    <script>
            $(function() { 
            $('#info').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
                $.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      url: 'ajax/ajax-info.php',
                      success: function(response) {
                          $('#result').html(response); 
                      }
                  });
              });
             });
     </script>
```

Any help of how to change it or where to locate it in either file to get it to work would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's `#info`? In your markup, the form has the id `form`

Comment: #info is the id of the form that is generated by first AJAX call into the DIV 'results'.  I want to then pass the variables of this form to 'ajax/ajax-info.php' and then output the results into the DIV 'results' again.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `live()` function to set events on a dynamically appears DOM element

```
<script>
        $(function() { 
        $('#info').live('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                  url: 'ajax/ajax-info.php',
                  success: function(response) {
                      $('#result').html(response); 
                  }
              });
          });
         });
 </script>
```

Comment: I'll try it, where would I put this script.  On to the PHP file that is loaded in, or the main HTML?  Cheers for the help.

Comment: On main HTML. By the way,  you hang two of the same event, it's can be done like this:
 
 `$('#form1, #info').live('submit', function(e) {`

Comment: But this submits it to the same PHP file each time doesn't it? I need the first call to reach 'ajax-details.php' and then the form outputted with that to each 'ajax-info.php'.

Comment: Yes, did not notice, how about this `$(this).attr('action')` instead of the address?

Comment: What do I put in the 'action'.  I'm quite new at this stuff, but cheers for the help!

Comment: `action` parametr of `form` element is a destination for data sending, should be 'ajax/ajax-details.php' and 'ajax/ajax-info.php'. it's parameter from  pure html, is not special associated with js. But it has the right value, so we can use it.

Comment: Ok yes, got that.  It now passes to the final PHP file but loads it up instead of inserting the results into the DIV 'results'.  I sense I'm close!  Cheers for all the help!

Comment: It can be some js syntax error, try to submit forms with open js console, firebug for example.